# Canvas shadow is cut off in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-canvas, shadow

I'm making a game with the HTML canvas element. I added a shadow to an image like so:

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'white';
ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
ctx.drawImage(ship, 100, 100, 50, 50);
```

It looks fine in Chrome:

[image]

But in Safari it get cut off:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Safari? I can't reproduce on 14.1.2 nor on TP 15.0. One possible workaround would be to render that image first on an empty canvas disconnected from the DOM of the same size as your output canvas and draw that canvas on your visible one with the shadow. An other thing you may try is to make the disconnected canvas just the size of the resized image (50 x 50), it may just be the resize params of drawImage that are causing this bug, or it may even only happen when the source is an <img>.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.